# fastest way to use cmaps in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I would like to create a column of color lists of type [r,g,b,a] from another float column using
a matplotlib cmap.

Is there a faster way then:

```
data.with_columns(
    pl.col("floatCol")/100)
        .map_elements(cmap1)
    )
```

Minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import polars as pl

cmap1 = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("GreenBlue", ["limegreen", "blue"])


data = pl.DataFrame(
    {
 "floatCol": [12,135.8, 1235.263,15.236],
 "boolCol": [True, True, False, False]
     }
    )

data = data.with_columns(
pl.when( 
    pl.col("boolCol").not_()
    )
    .then(
    mpl.colors.to_rgba("r")
    )
    .otherwise(
    (
        pl.col("floatCol")/100)
        .map_elements(cmap1)
        )
    .alias("c1")
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `map_elements`, then it can (nearly) always be faster ;)

```py
data.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("boolCol").not_())
    .then(mpl.colors.to_rgba("r"))
    .otherwise((pl.col("floatCol") / 100).map_batches(lambda x: pl.Series(cmap1(x))))
    .alias("c1")
)
```

Use `map_batches` to operate over the entire column

Comment: This is cool - it speeds up almost 2x :) Can I ask however what is the exact difference between map_batches and map_elements?

Comment: @Galedon https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/expressions/user-defined-functions/#to-map_batches-or-to-map_elements

Comment: The difference is that map_elements essentially runs a python for loop on each element one at a time whereas map_batches feeds the whole column as input to the function. If the function is optimized (vectorized) for array like input and output, the latter approach will be much faster.

Comment: From the docs "map_batches follows the same rules in both the select and the group_by". This statement is a tad vague. What it means is that map_batches is broken in group_by or over and will silently give you the same result as if you weren't trying to put it in a group or window.